# Find standard JSF tags for the corresponding Trinidad tags

Tags: jsf-2, trinidad

Is there any way can we find standard JSF 2 tags for the corresponding Trinidad tags?
Could anyone please help me on identifying the equivalent JSF 2 tags for the following list of Trinidad tags?

```
<tr:panelFormLayout> 
<tr:panelHorizontalLayout> 
<tr:goButton> 
<tr:spacer>
<tr:panelButtonBar>
<tr:panelHeader>
<tr:panelList>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no equivalent JSF 2 tags. They are just basic UI components you can combine with HTML and CSS to get to a point what Trinidad will provide you out of the box. It's like comparing apples to oranges.

Here is a good reference for [JSF tags](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/index.html) (core Faces, HTML, Composite, UI and JSTL).